# Optimising two arrays simultaneously with scipy optimize

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, optimization

I have a function that takes two m-dimensional arrays does some calculation with them (here it is very simplified) and returns one dimensional array. Also I have m-dimensional measurement data and would like to optimise those two arrays to fit the measurements. This worked fine with one arrays. I can just simply not get it to work with two arrays (or more). it always throws:

```
TypeError: Improper input: N=40 must not exceed M=20
```

Here is my Code. Thank you very much if anyone can help!

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize

data=[np.arange(0,20.0,1),np.array([-52.368, 32.221, 40.102, 48.088, 73.106, 50.807, 52.235, 76.933, 65.737, 34.772, 94.376, 123.366, 92.71, 72.25, 165.051, 91.501, 118.92, 100.936, 56.747, 159.034])]

def line(m,b):
   return m*b

guessm = np.ones(20)               #initial guessed values for m
guessb = np.ones(20)               #initial guesses values for b
guess = np.append(guessm,guessb)

errfunc= lambda p,y: (y-line(p[:20],p[20:]))
parameter, sucess = optimize.leastsq(errfunc, guess, args=(data[1]))

print(parameter)
plt.plot(data[0],d[1],'o')
plt.plot(data[0],line(parameter[0],parameter[1]))
plt.show()
```

Comment: your data[1] is a list, not an array, data[0] has 19 elements, data[1] has 20, and your model vector is 40? It's not very clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @sulkeh Hey, I fixed it, so it should be more clear now. `optimize.leastsq` takes one array as guesses. But i want to optimise two arrays at the same time. So I combined my two arrays into one array for the LM-algorithm to optimise. But then it raises the errors, that this 40-long array ist not 20 entries long. So to summarize: I have a function, dependant of two parameters: `m` and `b`. I also have measurement data `data` where `m[i] * b[i] = data[i]` . Task is to find `m` and `b` arrays.

Comment: Then you have twice as many unknowns (40) as equations (20).

Comment: Yeah, you are totally right on that one :D thank you very much. That was the problem. To obvious to get for me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fit a line, you should give the slope and intercept - two parameters, not 40. I suspect this is what you try to do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize

data=[np.arange(0,20.0,1),np.array([-52.368, 32.221, 40.102, 48.088, 73.106, 50.807, 52.235, 76.933, 65.737, 34.772, 94.376, 123.366, 92.71, 72.25, 165.051, 91.501, 118.92, 100.936, 56.747, 159.034])]

def line(m,b):
   return np.arange(0, 20, 1)*m + b

guess = np.ones(2)

errfunc= lambda p,y: (y-line(p[0],p[1]))
parameter, sucess = optimize.leastsq(errfunc, guess, args=(data[1]))

print(parameter)
plt.plot(data[0],data[1],'o')
plt.plot(data[0],line(parameter[0],parameter[1]))
plt.show()
```

Comment: `guess = np.ones(2)`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist edited now. It was written that way because of the code in the question

Comment: I understood why you did it, but it looked so awkward I had to say something. LGTM.